# How to set layout BEHIND AndEngine scene?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, andengine, surfaceview

Does anyone know how to orient your main layout so that it is behind an Andengine scene?

What I am trying to do is overlay some AndEngine controls on top of a video stream that fills the whole screen. My video stream comes from a website, so I'm using WebView.

I thought to set the background as transparent, so that a layout could be shown underneath, but I don't know how to orient the layout this way. Basically, I'd welcome ANY way by which I can display my webview as the "background" of my app while still having the controls (that are similar to [AnalogOnScreenControls](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AnalogOnScreenControlsExample.java)) visible overtop (in the bottom left and top right corner).

If not possible, I'd settle for just implementing a webview into my andengine code, which I've done some research on, but have never actually successfully done. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Check out the AugmentedRealityExample in the andengine examples. It features Sprites drawn ove live camera feed.

http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AugmentedRealityExample.java?spec=svndc80a85976df8d8f49268a4c0b64c3ac6be5c328&r=07a5aabdd0ce738a624863ca8d18895350a23356

It appears the trick is to just create a scene with a transparent background:
scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));

Be suire to check the superclass "BaseAugmentedRealityGameActivity" to see where he attaches the camera feed using a "CameraPreviewSurfaceView". The cameraPreviewSurfaceView extends plain old Vanilla Android.SurfaceView - so from that starting point you should be able to get accomplished what you need.